# Can't delete NortonForMac.kext

Tags: kernel-extensions

I downloaded Norton for my MacBook Pro 2018 13 inch a few months ago, and after uninstalling it, according to the instructions given by the official Norton FAQ, some files remained in my computer that couldn't be deleted by dragging them to the bin. I ran another program designed by Norton to exclusively eliminate any leftover files from the antivirus program itself, and I still can't get rid of one final file: NortonForMac.kext. My MacOS is in Spanish, so the directory in which it appears to be stored in is /Macintosh HD/Biblioteca/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions. Can someone help me delete it?

Comment: Are you on macOS Mojave or Catalina? I'm not sure for Catalina as system files are now on a seperate partition I believe? But with macOS Mojave and earlier, you may be able to delete it by disabling System Integrity Protection. I personally wouldn't tinker too much with kernel extensions, so be very careful with it. Hope this helps

Comment: I'm on MacOS Catalina.